# curious case of time lag needed between unlock and notify_one call

Tags: c++11

Please have a look on below code. I could not understand the behavior.Sleep or time lag is needed on the highlighted line to end the program

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <deque>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <condition_variable>
std::mutex m;
std::deque<packaged_task<void()> >task_queue;
atomic<bool> quit;
atomic<bool> done;
condition_variable cond_var;

bool shutdown_event()
{
    return quit ;

}
void button_press()
{
    std::cout<<"button presss event \n";
}
void cursor_move()
{
    std::cout<<"cursor move event \n";
}
void gui_consumer_thread()
{

    while(!shutdown_event())
    {
        packaged_task<void()>task;
        {
            std::unique_lock<mutex>mut(m);
            if(task_queue.empty())
            {
                done.store(true);
                mut.unlock();
                //usleep(1000); //if i skip this sleep than program hangs
                //std::cout<<"task queue is empty\n";
                cond_var.notify_one();
                continue;
            }
            task= move(task_queue.front());
            task_queue.pop_front();
           // mut.unlock();
        }
        task();
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"shutting down\n";
}
template<typename T>
void gui_producer_thread(T f)
{
    std::packaged_task<void()>t(f);
    std::lock_guard<mutex>mut(m);
    std::cout<<"adding to queue\n";
    task_queue.push_back(std::move(t));
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    quit=false;
    done = false;
    std::thread t(gui_consumer_thread);
    std::vector<std::function<void()> >f{button_press,cursor_move};
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
        gui_producer_thread(f.at(rand()%2));
    std::unique_lock<mutex>mut(m);
    cond_var.wait(mut,[&](){return done.load();});
    quit=true;
    t.join();
    //f.push_back(button_loadpress);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above with time lag between notify_all and unlock program hangs at the end .But not otherwise.
I have removed some functions ,so that scenario can be understood easily

Comment: This code doesn't compile, let alone run. Off the top, `quit` and `done` are undeclared identifiers. Show [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: my bad, I should not expect people to tell by static analysis only in such scenarios. I have added whole program code. please check now.

Comment: I think you observe [starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)). Right off the start, `gui_consumer_thread` enters a busy loop where it constantly locks, sees the queue empty, unlocks, calls `notify_one` and immediately locks again; lather, rinse, repeat. The window during which `m` is left unlocked is very narrow, the main thread just can't squeeze its own lock through. By sleeping or emitting output, you widen that window. Normally, you'd have another condition variable for "queue not empty or quit" condition that the consumer can wait on, avoiding busy loop.